# Getting the first element of each nested array in Presto

Tags: hadoop, presto

I have an array of arrays and I want to get an array of the first elements of each inner array. I tried using `transform`, but I got:

```
not yet implemented: com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.LambdaExpression
```

Here's my query:

```
select transform(texts, text -> text[1]) from foo limit 10;
```

Is there a way without lambdas?